# PHP get value from associative array by variable from loop

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm not sure my question is right.

I have made a html table and filled it with test data from the database.

Image from the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3mYk.jpg

This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered turnover_list">
<thead>
    <tr class="sorting_1">
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>January</th>
        <th>February</th>
        <th>March</th>
        <th>April</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>June</th>
        <th>July</th>
        <th>August</th>
        <th>September</th>
        <th>October</th>
        <th>November</th>
        <th>December</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php

        $currentYear = date('Y');

        $check = "SELECT * FROM turnover WHERE year = '" . $currentYear . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($check) or die(mysql_error());

        foreach ($allCompanies as $companyName) {

            $companyTurnoverTotal = 0;
            $turnoverTotal = 0;

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . $companyName . "</td>";
            echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . $currentYear . "</td>";

            $monthTotal = array("January"=>"0", "February"=>"0", "March"=>"0", "April"=>"0", "May"=>"0", "June"=>"0", "July"=>"0", "August"=>"0", "September"=>"0", "October"=>"0", "November"=>"0", "December"=>"0");

            foreach ($months as $month) {
                $sql = "SELECT SUM(mob + www) AS 'turnover' FROM turnover WHERE year = '" . $currentYear . "' AND companyID = '" . getCompanyID($companyName) . "' AND month = '" . $month . "'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $companyTurnoverMonth = $row['turnover'];

                $monthTotal[$month] += $companyTurnoverMonth;
                echo "<script>alert('" . $month . ": " . $monthTotal[$month] . "')</script>";

                $companyTurnoverTotal += $companyTurnoverMonth;
                $turnoverTotal += $companyTurnoverTotal;

                echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($companyTurnoverMonth) . "</td>";
            }
            echo "<td style='width:7%; font-weight: bold; background-color:#d3d3d3;'>" . make_format($companyTurnoverTotal) . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold; background-color:#d3d3d3;'>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . "Total" . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . $currentYear . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['January']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['February']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['March']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['April']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['May']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['June']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['July']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['August']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['September']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['October']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['November']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($monthTotal['December']) . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($turnoverTotal) . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    ?>

</tbody>
```

I want a table column at the right that shows the total of every company.
At the bottom of the table I want a row with columns per month that shows the total of every month.

I was trying to make an array with all the months and increase the value with the next column in the same month. `$monthTotal[$month] += $companyTurnoverMonth;`

```
foreach ($months as $month) {
                $sql = "SELECT SUM(mob + www) AS 'turnover' FROM turnover WHERE year = '" . $currentYear . "' AND companyID = '" . getCompanyID($companyName) . "' AND month = '" . $month . "'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $companyTurnoverMonth = $row['turnover'];

                $monthTotal[$month] += $companyTurnoverMonth;

                $companyTurnoverTotal += $companyTurnoverMonth;
                $turnoverTotal += $companyTurnoverTotal;

                echo "<td style='width:7%;'>" . make_format($companyTurnoverMonth) . "</td>";
            }
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: what is your question exactly? also a little tip: style the width of your columns with css, dont use inline stylings like that. otherwise each time you want to change the width you will have to change 19 occurrencies. (you might actually want to change 7% to 6%, because you have 15 columns at 7% width = 105% width)

Comment: My question is, how to access an associative array with a key variable from a loop. For example I have an array with the 12 months called $months and the associated array called $monthTotal ("January" =>"0", "February"=>"0", and so on). Foreach $months as $month. I need to access $monthTotal by the foreach variable called $month so can make the foreach like this: foreach $months as $month { echo $monthTotal[$month]